# How to get particular value from fixture file in cypress

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, cypress

I retrieve below-mentioned code snippet as the response of a request

How can I retrieve "id", if I search based on Username in JSON Response
For an example - How can I get a response with "id" value as 1 when I search on the name "Leanne Graham"

Note Response Values and their positions are dynamic

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Leanne Graham",
    "username": "Bret",
    "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
    "address": {
      "street": "Kulas Light",
      "suite": "Apt. 556",
      "city": "Gwenborough",
      "zipcode": "92998-3874",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-37.3159",
        "lng": "81.1496"
      }
    },
    "phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
    "website": "hildegard.org",
    "company": {
      "name": "Romaguera-Crona",
      "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
      "bs": "harness real-time e-markets"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Ervin Howell",
    "username": "Antonette",
    "email": "Shanna@melissa.tv",
    "address": {
      "street": "Victor Plains",
      "suite": "Suite 879",
      "city": "Wisokyburgh",
      "zipcode": "90566-7771",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-43.9509",
        "lng": "-34.4618"
      }
    },
    "phone": "010-692-6593 x09125",
    "website": "anastasia.net",
    "company": {
      "name": "Deckow-Crist",
      "catchPhrase": "Proactive didactic contingency",
      "bs": "synergize scalable supply-chains"
    }
  }
  
]
```

Comment: Array.find() with default, and object deconstruction will get the id, or undefined if not found - `const {id} = response.find(user => user.name === 'Leanne Graham') || {};`. But I suspect there's more to the question. How does it relate to a Cypress test?

Comment: I would like to make a custom function for finding the usedid based on Username and In that i would like to load whole array from fixture file

Answer (score 0):

If the username is a unique value, this is a way to do it.

```
let users  = YOUR_JSON_LIST;
let idUser = users.find(u => u.username == SOME_USERNAME).id;
```

If the search attribute is not constrained to an unique value, you can get a list of values using map

```
let usersIdList = users
  .filter(u => u.website == SOME_WEBSITE)
  .map(u => u.id);
```